# How can we check whether we have non zero data in SQL Server database or not?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, database, datatable, datatables

I have a database in SQL Server that gets updated every hour on a daily basis. My task is to develop a script/code that can check at every hour that whether we have received non zero data in the database for that hour or not.

If we have received non zero data, then I need to update count by 1. The count should be set to 0 initially. I have to monitor this for 24 hours i.e. for a day. So suppose, we had non zero data for whole the day, i.e. for 24 hours, then at the end of the day, the count should be 24 and that count data will be sent via email to me (will have to develop python script for email).

Next day, we should again start from count 0 and start checking the same and repeat the whole procedure.

I tried using triggers but they detect the change occurred in data not whether we have non zero data or not. I created a trigger in SQL Server and accessed SQL database via python, and based on the count I receive after 24 hours, I sent it to an email id via python also.

Ultimate aim is to check at every hour for 24 straight hours that whether we had data in the SQL Server database or not, if yes then whether it was non zero or not, if yes then count should be updated from 0 to the number of times we had non zero data and that count should be sent via email.

Comment: What is "non-zero data"? What if the row has 2 numerical columns, of which one is `0` and the other not? is that "zero data" or "non-zero data"? Both?

Comment: Non zero data as in there should be some data. Like I agree there could be 0 values in some rows but what I mean is if all the values are 0 then we should not update the count. @Larnu

Comment: Sample data, expected results and your attempt(s) will help clarify what you're after here.

Comment: I think I was little bit unclear in that part. Let us justs ay that we want to check whether we had some data or not.

Comment: Check the value of your "Date Inserted" and keep of log of when you check. If the maximum date inserted value is larger than the last check, you had data.

Comment: The columns are the speed of vehicles, number of potholes on roads, number of vehicles passed, etc.This data gets updated every hour automatically using a python script in SQL server database. Now my job is that I just need to make sure that the data gets updated every hour. Therefore, I want to check that data gets updated every hour or not and for that I need to write some script. Does this make more sense? Please let me know.

Comment: You just need to check your "date inserted" column; as you said there will be no rows if there is no data.

Comment: If you don't have such a column, you need to add one, unless you have some *other* way of knowing rows were added? But if you did, you wouldn't be asking the question, so hence the flaw with the design.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have that column in the database. Like triggers check whether the data has been modified or not and if yes then we can update a column called count as c = c + 1, is there any way we can do that to check whether we hace data in database and if yes, then we increment the count by 1 and update the coult column?

Comment: Triggers check at the time of the insert, they occur as part of the DML operation, you can't have a "retrospective trigger". If *you* can't tell if new rows have been added to a table, how do you suppose SQL Server will?